# Symfony query wrong result

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm using a personal request in symfony witch is:

```
public function findByReferenceUser($Reference, $User)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select('a')
        ->join('a.Reference', 'r')
        ->where('r.id = :refId')
        ->setParameter("refId", $Reference->getId())
        ->join('a.User', 'u')
        ->andWhere('u.id = :userId')
        ->setParameter("userId", $User->getId());

    return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

But it doesn't work properly.
I'm getting 3 results witch are of type NULL,NULL, Boolean. I'm using this to check it:

```
    $list_article = $RArticle->findByReferenceUser($reference, $panier->getUser());
    foreach ($list_article as $key => $article)
        echo gettype($article);
```

My database works, and have the right informations.
Finnaly, this works:

```
    $list_article = $RArticle->findAll();
    foreach ($list_article as $key => $article)
        echo gettype($article);
```

And print object, object.

So there is my questions: Why do I get NULL, NULL, Boolean in the first case and how do I fixe it?

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: try to change `$qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();` to `$qb->getQuery()->getResult();`

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for because I do want only one result witch in my case should not be null. Also, OneOrNull should set $list_article to null but it doesn't so it might not be the problem.

Comment: ok, try to print output of the `$list_article` with `var_dump` (whitout foreach)..

Answer (score 1):

When using `getOneOrNullResult`, Doctrine will `Retrieve a single object. If no object is found null will be returned.` [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html).

If you want several object, you should use `getResult`

Answer (score 0):

`findAll()` returns array of objects, such as `array('key' => 'object')`, that's why you are getting correct records,  `getOneOrNullResult()` returns single object (not array, `foreach` won't work), if you want to retrieve multiple records you need to use `getResult()`

Comment: You're right! I'm might be tied cause I knew it...
So yes, the result is directly an object so no need to use foreach.
Thank for the help. ^^